# storing several matrices on one object

Tags: julia

I have this simple econometrics/statistics exercise that I'm trying to implement in Julia. I've never used Julia before, and I have already done this code in R, but I cant seem to translate the code.

Here is the outline: I have an inner loop where for a fixed N, I draw K samples from a distribution, and I store them in a matrix that is N x K. I do this for two matrices, them multiply each column of each matrix (obtaining a 2x1 vector) them and store in a 2 x K matrix.

After that, I do an outer loop for, say, 5 different values of N. In the end, I would like to have 5 different matrices that are 2 x K, so that I can plot them. What I can't figure out is how to store efficiently this matrix. In R, I would simply put them in a list, and call them each out for calculations.

```
using Distributions
using StatsBase
J = 500
N = [10 100 500 1000 10000]
i = 1
b = ones(3,J)
for n in N
    x = ones(n,J)
    e = ones(n,J)
    y = ones(n,J)
    for j = 1:J
        x[:,j] = rand(Normal(3,1),n)
        y[:,j] = 3 + 2.5*x[:,j] + e[:,j]
        x = [y[:,j] x[:,j]]
        b[:,j] = inv(y'*x)*(x'*y[:,j])
    end
    i = i + 1
    i
end
```

I've tried with this code, but it doesn't seem to work at all. I can't even make this simple for loop below work:

```
for i = 1:10
    x = ones(i, 10)
end
```

I get a `ERROR: UndefVarError: x not defined`. Can you guys help me?

Comment: It is always better to post some working code. Even the R code you are referring to. BTW the for loop at the end works. Restart Julia and type it in the REPL and see what happens.

Comment: Also, you can't do `inv(y'*x)` as you can only take the inverse of a square matrix

Comment: sorry, it should be b[:.j] = inv(x'*x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd simply put them in a `Vector{Matrix}`, a vector of matrices.
But a common paradigm in Julia would be to instead define a function `f`that does what you want, and then broadcast that function over N, i.e. by calling `a = f.(N)` (N should be a Vector, not a Matrix, BTW, so commas between the numbers rather than spaces).

So, say you want to store 5 Matrices that are 2 x K with varying K. There are in fact numerous ways you can do that, depending on taste, style, convenience, etc. Here are some examples, where k varies from 20 to 24:

```
# a python-style list comprehension
mymatrices = [randn(K,2) for K in 20:24]

# a function broadcast over the array
f(k) = randn(k,2)
mymatrices = f.(20:24)

# a Vector with preallocated elements
mymatrices = Vector{Matrix{Float64}}(5)
for (i, k) in enumerate(20:24)   #enumerate is smart
    mymatrices[i] = randn(k, 2)
end    

# a Vector that grows dynamically
mymatrices = Matrix{Float64}[] # shorter optional syntax for an empty vector
for (i, k) in enumerate(20:24)
    push!(mymatrices, randn(k, 2))
end  

# map with an anonymous function
mymatrices = map(k -> randn(k,2), 20:24)
```

Comment: could you give me a quick example? i don't understand the logic of julia, i tried doing simply "a[i] = b" after the inner loop, but that doesn't work. how do i define a empty array that can store N matrices?

Comment: `a = Matrix{Float64}[]` or `a = Vector{Matrix{Float64}}()` . But I've updated my answer with a different approach.

Comment: It's a little hard to answer as I cannot see how your code corresponds to what you describe... What is the matrix you'd like to put in a vector?

Comment: the inner loop creates a 2 x K matrix, and the outer loop does this 5 times for different values of N (that are used to compute the inner loop matrix). So in the end, I would like to have 5 2xK matrices in one object, and be able to call any of them and then use their lines to plot histograms.

Comment: if you go carefully through all those examples you should get the picture

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! It really helped, I've posted my own code as an answer, but I'm obviously accepting yours!

Answer (score 2):

So after help from you guys and some more googleing, i've come up with this code that works. Not sure if this violates the purpose of StackOverflow, but I'm posting my answer. If you guys have time, please criticize, it seems a little too verbose, I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
using Distributions

N = [10, 100, 500, 1000, 10000]
J = 500
bet = Vector{Matrix{Float64}}()

for n in N
    b = Array{Float64, 2}(3, J)
    for j = 1:J
        x1 = Array{Float64, 2}(n,J)
        x2 = Array{Float64, 2}(n,J)
        epsilon = Array{Float64, 2}(n,J)
        y = Array{Float64, 2}(n,J)
        cons = ones(n)
        x1[:,j] = rand(Normal(3,1),n)
        x2[:,j] = rand(Normal(-1,1),n)
        epsilon[:,j] = rand(Normal(0,1),n)
        y[:,j] = 3 + 2.5*x1[:,j] + 4*x2[:,j] + epsilon[:,j]
        x = [cons x1[:,j] x2[:,j]]
        b[:,j] = inv(x'*x)*(x'*y[:,j])
    end
    push!(bet, b)
end
```

Comment: On the contrary, answering your own question is encouraged here. Don't be afraid to accept your own answer with the green checkmark button on the left.

Answer (score 1):

The loop works fine, and `x` is set correctly inside, but `x` is out of scope once the loop ends, and so is undefined.

```
julia> for i = 1:10
           x = ones(i, 10)
       end

julia> x
ERROR: UndefVarError: x not defined
```

If you create it first:

```
julia> x = Array{Float64}(10, 10);

julia> for i = 1:10
           x = ones(i, 10)
       end

julia> x
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

then it stays in scope.